# If (condition) is true for all $x \in X$, does there exist an $x$ such that it has such a condition for all $x \in X$?

Tags: logic, quantifiers

If $\forall x \in X$, (condition) is true, is it then also true to say $\exists x$ such that (condition holds) $\forall x \in X$?

Comment: Formally this makes little sense, because you're bounding the same variable $x$ with two different quantifiers, first an existential and then a universal one. Can you put this in a clearer way?

Comment: I understand it's a bit formally awkward, that's the intent is to clear something up that's a bit awkward.

Comment: No this is not always true. For example $\forall x \in \emptyset,$ (condition), but there is no $x \in \emptyset$.

Comment: maybe you want to ask whether $\exists x$ (condition) holds for each $x$ in $X$. The problem is that the $x$ appearing after $\exists$ is not  a particular element of $X$. For example, if $X = \{1,2,3\}$, and the condition is $x < 4$ it simply makes no sense to write $\exists 2$ with 2 meaning the element of $X$.

Comment: No @Mathy for $x \in \emptyset$ the condition is a vacuous truth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand the downvotes, this is actually an interesting question. It boils down to whether you allow vacuous quantifiers (many systems don't), that is quantifiers that do not bind any variable.

Let's say that your condition is $P$ and I'm going to change from the extensive formulation of $x \in X$ to $x$ has property $F$.

So $\forall x \in X, \text{(condition is true)}$ becomes $\forall x (Fx \to Px)$ which is a closed formula, call it $\phi$. What you're asking is whether $\exists x\phi$ is true... it depends, if you allow empty domains then no. If you allow for vacuous quantifiers (without  empty domains) then it makes sense to let $\exists x\phi$ be logically equivalent to $\phi$, and the same with the universal quantifier.

Know though that these formulae do not correspond to any meaningful english sentence, it's just a pure logical shibboleth.

Comment: I like the interesting answer, which did address what was originally asked literally (but not what it was edited to later).

Comment: @JohnStell I think it still does actually.

Comment: What is an example of one of these "many systems" that don't allow vacuous quantifiers?  I've never heard of any such thing.

Comment: @EricWofsey From the top of my head Smith and Van Dalen don't allow for vacuous quantifiers, whereas Bostock does.

Comment: I just checked, the Open Logic Project also allows for vacuous quantifiers (p. 190).

Comment: Thank you, @Simone ! I appreciate it!

Comment: @Simone yes, your answer clearly does work (I had trouble figuring out what the question was)